# Using Variable to Query Resources Dynamically

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

Is it possible to use a variable when querying multiple resources in log analytics? This is what I have now:

```
let all = app('app-insights-1').dependencies | union app('app-insights-2').dependencies; all | where type == 'SQL' and success == false
```

Is it possible to parameterise the above? For example:

```
let foo = 'app-insights-1'
let all = app(foo).dependencies | union app('app-insights-2').dependencies; all | where type == 'SQL' and success == false
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our environment & understood that we cannot initialize the identifier with a variable & pass it  to app(identifier).
[image]

- Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/app-expression) , below arguments can only be passed to the app(identifier) expression.

[image]